# Magento, Display Yes/No attribute filter in the layered navigation

Tags: magento, attributes

I have created New attribute as Yes/No type in the Magento admin.
I just would like to display this attribute in the frontend, but Magento doesn't support Yes/No type attribute for Use In Layered Navigation.

Anyone help me to do it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

You could add it as a dropdown, and then add just two options, Yes and No.

That would be a very easy work around :)

Comment: thanks for your reply. problem is yes/no type attribute is already created on the site now. in this case, it can be done?

Comment: Yes/No fields are not supported in Magento's layered navigation. Unless you're in a position to write a custom module which adds support, the answer by @Andrew is the best option.